# Multi touch gesture terminology

Tags: mobile, terminology, multitouch

What term would you use to describe the type of touch gesture whereby the user touches a point on screen, and an object moves (ease-out) to the location where the finger is touching the screen?

Can you tell me the names of the different types of multi-touch gestures (screen-based) such as tap, swipe, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You seem to be describing a *single press* gesture.

I would call it a ***single press***. I believe your understanding of *touch gestures* might be wrong, as I would not call the event you describe a *touch gesture*. I would call it a *response* to a particular touch gesture.

---

#### Let's break down your description into the *action* and the *reaction*.

> the user touches a point on screen

That, in itself, completely describes the event where the user interacts with the screen. This describes the interaction where a user simply touches the screen; a ***single press***.

> an object moves (ease-out) to the location where the finger is touching the screen

This is your *reaction* to the gesture of touching the screen. If you wish to describe the *event*, I would call it a "mouse follow" or "beacon follow", where your element follows the *mouse cursor* (excuse the analogy) or a *beacon* that you place down during your input.

---

#### Gesture terminology

> Can you tell me the names of the different types of multi-touch gestures (screen-based) such as tap, swipe, etc.?

To me, this appears to be a difficult question, especially given the lack of context. Do you simply wish to know of the *alternates* available to you through a multi-touch input device, or do you actually wish to know for the purpose of deliberately implementing them? Different platforms can have different names for the same gesture, and as a result, names you hear might be *correct* but not actually *work* if taken literally in implementation.

- Slide
- Drag
- Swipe
- Press
- Long press
- Multi-press
- Press and hold
- Pinch in
- Pinch out

Comment: Is a tap and a press the same? If so, I would say a long press is analogous to the beacon follow example. By pressing on the screen, the object moves to the x,y co-ordinaes where the finger is touching the screen.

Comment: @Vyas, in a "beacon follow" example, the initial input places down a beacon, which gives the object the position to move to. Consider "mouse follow" to be real-time, and "beacon follow" to be a pre-determined position. If you need to press down for a set period of time before input is registered in the way you describe, it would be a long press. If input is registered instantaneously, it would be a simple press. If your object loses its position the second you release your finger from the screen, it would be a *hold* using a *mouse follow* event.